# How to get data from a classes data received event to MainWindow to update the UI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I am creating a program which reads in .csv data from an Arduino which is connected to 3 different sensors. 
This data is read from a Serial class and sent to a ParseData class which adds the .csv data to a List and
sends it off to the 3 classes for each sensor. (The data from all three sensors is sent at the same time from the Arduino and parsed from the ParseData class)

Three Classes:  Sensor1, Sensor2, Sensor3

DataModels:     SensorDataModel1, SensorDataModel2, SensorDataModel3

I want to update a chart in MainWindow.xaml/MainWindow.xaml.cs with data from three different classes as a line on the graph. I want to be notified in MainWindow that these three sensors have new data and then to update the graph with the data. I am not sure if I have to subscribe to an event for each sensor or something similar.

```
// SerialCommunication.cs - read in data and send to ArduinoDataReceived() method for parsing
private void OnDataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string serialBuffer = sp.ReadLine();

        // Send the subscriber the data received
        if (DataReceived != null)
        {
            DataReceived?.Invoke(this, new SerialDataReceivedEventArgs()
            {
                dataReceived = serialBuffer
            });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
}


// ParseData.cs - subscribed to SerialCommunication.cs event and receives the data string and sends data to each sensors class
private void ArduinoDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Sensor1 sensor1 = new Sensor1();
    Sensor2 sensor2 = new Sensor2();
    Sensor3 sensor3 = new Sensor3();

    // parse all sensor data from Arduino to a list which holds all three sensors data
    List<string> sensorData = e.ToString().Split(',').ToList();

    // parse list for each sensor and send off to each class to process the data
    sensor1.AddData(sensorData1);
    sensor2.AddData(sensorData2);
    sensor3.AddData(sensorData3);
}


// SensorData1.cs - an example of storing the data and adding it to a List of the Sensors data model
public List<SensorDataModel1> ListSensorData1 = new List<SensorDataModel1>();

public void AddData(List<string> data, long dataLength)
{
    SensorDataModel1 s1 = new SensorDataModel1();

    s1.Add(data[0]);
    s1.Add(data[1]);
    s1.Add(data[2]);

    ListSensorData1.Add(s1);
}
```

I expect all three Data classes to send the data back to MainWindow and for MainWindow to update the Chart with these values each time they are read in from the serial port.

Comment: You want the MainWindow ViewModel or code behind, whichever you're using to have an instance of each of the classes and subscribe to their updated / recieved method, and then use that as the point to redraw / add info to your graph.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have an instance of each of the classes in the MainWindow, all three classes have an AddData() method which updates a List but I don't have any events in these classes to subscribe to?

Comment: Perhaps there is something in the SerialCommunication class?

Comment: So should I change my architecture where in my parse data class that is subscribed to the serial receive event, should I then pass the data to each sensor class by an event instead of calling and AddData() method? I thought some sort of INotifyPropertyChanged or ObservableCollection would be able to solve my issue but I am not quite sure how to implement it

Comment: The second half of your reply seems like a good idea to try out. Create 3 properties on your class for each of the sensors, the `propfull` code snippet will help, and then have your class Implement INotifyPropertyChanged and each property call it on set, 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8 Should help you figure out how to impliment it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing how your entire archetecture is setup I can only assume. What i would most likely do in your situation is the following:

1) have your main window subscribe to the `SerialDataReceivedEventArgs` such that the event will be raised in the code behind of the main window. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13849850/6552757) should be a good starting place to hook that together. This will allow you to update the Data from your MainWindow.

2) If you are using a viewmodel and binding the data; then i would create a Command or method to add the new sensor data to your collections. In your viewmodel i would create an `ObservableCollection` for each Sensor and then use Binding to attach them to the MainWindow.

```
//MainWindow XAML
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<YourControl1 ItemSource={Binding Source=SensorData1}/>
<YourControl2 ItemSource={Binding Source=SensorData2}/>
<YourControl3 ItemSource={Binding Source=SensorData3}/>
```

3) In your MainWindow code behind (or in XAML if you want to be fancy creating new events) you can then call the ViewModel Command or Method to update the data. Using the names from the link above:

```
// inside MainWindow.xaml.cs
private void DisplaySerDataHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   var newSensorData1;
   //...This is where you set all the new sensor data you received to the variables. 
   var dContext = DataContext as MainWindowViewModel;
   dContext?.SetNewSensorData(newSensorData1, newSensorData2, newSensorData3);
}
```

4) Inside MainWindowViewModel.cs you can then have the business logic to alter the ObservableCollections which will update when added to and automagically update the UI elements.

```
//you need an ObservableCollection for each list
public ObservableCollection<sensorType> SensorData1 {get;set;}

//then create the command or method to add the data to their respective Collection
public void SetNewSensorData(sensorType sData1, sensorType sData2, sensorType sData3){

  //...then add the new data (with extra logic as needed)
  SensorData1.add(sData1);
  SensorData2.add(sData2);
  SensorData3.add(sData3);
}
```

There are many other elements that can/should be done. This was meant as an example as to how you could update the mainwindow controls with the incoming serialized data. It would be up to you how you want everything to be designed. Your `MainWindowViewModel` would implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I prefer the use of Commands as I can then try to remove code from the code behind and bind everything in XAML and then all my logic can be contained in the ViewModel. That is not a right or wrong way to do it, just my preference. I prefer to have code behind that is only used to specifically change the Control elements themselves and all other business logic is in the ViewModel.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. This is a great answer and has helped me a lot. After looking at this and getting a bit more knowledge of MVVM I have removed my code from the code behind completely and I am currently implementing Commands, thank you.